# What's Spanish for "Skid-steer loader"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, construcción-y-obra

My kid, like most kids, has an inclination for construction vehicles. Sometimes, he'll pick a book full of construction-vehicle vocabulary for me to read and, when that book is in English, I often find myself translating on the fly to broaden his vocabulary and keep him used to Spanish.

That challenged me to learn some of the names of the construction vehicles I wasn't familiar with or never cared to know in Spanish (a backhoe loader is a *retroexcavadora*, a dump truck is a *volquete*, etc).

I don't know what Spanish for a Skid-steer loader is. A [skid-steer loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skid-steer_loader) (skid-steer loader, or skidsteer) is

> a small, rigid-frame, engine-powered machine with lift arms used to attach a wide variety of labor-saving tools or attachments.

So it is like a loader (*pala cargadora*), but much smaller and with a different loader mechanism (a skid loader mechanism instead of a "tractor-like" loader mechanism).

Can anybody tell me what we call a **skid-steer loader** in Spanish?

[image] [image]

Comment: Just to be pedantic here, "skid steer" refers to how the machine turns and not the mechanism attached to the arms.  It literally turns by skidding the left/right sets of wheels by applying a differential speed to each side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems they are called *cargadoras **compactas***:

> [image]
>
> - https://www.cat.com/es_ES/products/new/equipment/skid-steer-loaders.html

> [image]
>
> - https://www.bobcat.com/eu/es/cargadoras/cargadoras-compactas/caracteristicas

Answer (score 5):

En Colombia se les conoce sencillamente por el nombre de una de las marcas "**bobcat**".

Comment: Y posiblemente esa empresa tenga la patente o algo, y sea la única que las fabrica (no toda la maquinaria es un "bobcat", pero todos los skid steers son bobcat)

Comment: @Diego posiblemente fue primera marca que tuvo presencia en Colombia o la que la mayor participación tiene del mercado (ya que por la foto es claro que Caterpillar también fabrica esos aparatos).

Comment: No se si somos solo los Colombianos pero aquí ya ha pasado antes con otras marcas. Aquí tradicionalmente hemos llamado a los "bulldozer" **catapila** como una deformación/adaptación de la marca Caterpillar. Con los bobcat pasó lo mismo +1

Answer (score 1):

In Uruguay we name that kind of machines

> Pala mecánica

A "Pala" (without "mecánica") is just a normal shovel and "mecánica" means mechanical.

That being said, I'm not a professional in the branch, that meaning if I see this machine on the streets I will name it "Pala mecánica" but maybe the worker working on it may name it with a more precise or descriptive name.

Answer (score 0):

En España además les llamamos Mini PalaRetro o Bobcats o Carga

Answer (score 0):

Mini-Pala para Pala cargadora.
Mini-Retro para Máquina con retro.

Comment: Bienvenido! ¿Puedes indicar la región donde se usan estas palabras?